# C# Winforms DatagridView - setting different Color of button for different row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcheckboxcell

**EDIT: trying to excute the following code in Winforms.**

I am fetching the data from xml & they are shown in the datagridview using custom class i have created.I have linked every column with `DataPropertyName`

I want to show datagridview textboxes, buttoncolumn , checkbox in datagrid  like the following image.

[image]

I am using following event to change the color of the button i have added. For particular element, suppose i am binding `dt` to the single row of grid, then

```
if(dt.val=="true")
          {
// change the color of that button
          }
```

i am using following code.

```
 private void Grid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
DataGridViewColumn dt = Grid.Columns[9]; // 9 is column no

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in Grid.Rows)
            { 
                if (newList[r.Index].val.ToString() == "true") //some condition
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = red; // this turns compete row red

                   // add something here to make button red of this row 
                }
             else 
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = green;
                   // add something here to make button red of this row 

                }


            }
}
```

1. I am unable to change the color of particular cell button.
2. How do i add checkboxes in last row, as i have already added DataGridViewCheckboxColumn but by default grid is not showing any column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would change the background color of a specific cell like this:

```
r.Cells(9).Style.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
```